# How do you force jQuery form submit calls to utilize an angular ng-submit?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, form-submit

I am calling $('form').submit in a jQuery function. The HTML of this form includes an angular ng-submit binding. I want the jQuery call to respect the angular ng-submit. It is currently utilizing the default submit functionality instead (which includes a page refresh).

How do I force jQuery to use the ng-submit provided function instead of the default submit function? Below are relevant code excerpts.

Please let me know if I can provide any useful information.

```js
$scope.do_submit = function(){
  // some logic here
};

$("#input").autocomplete({
  // some logic
  
  select: function(event, ui){
    $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
    
    //this calls the default submit, not the ng-submit for the form.
    $(event.target.form).submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id='text_form' ng-submit="do_submit()"><input id='input' ng-model="user_answer" autofocus></form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a hidden submit button to your markup:
`<input type="submit" class="submit" style="display: none" />`

Then, instead of submitting your form directly, let jQuery send a click to the submit button:
`$('.submit', $(event.target.form)).click();`

By doing this, Angular will take over and honor your ng-submit attribute.